# Java Full GC - Floating Garbage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Currently I am learning about GC in Java, but I need some clarification. Let's say we have situation like on this picture:

[image]

According to this [website](https://plumbr.io/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations) first runs DefNew and after that Tenured GC. In that case:

- In DefNew Object A has reference from Old generation, this won't be collected.
- In Tenured (if I get it right), Object B won't be deleted because has a reference from Young Generation (Object A).

How does it works after all? I was thinking about dirty cards, but only Object C would be marked, because it was changed (deleted reference to Object B).

Answer (score 0):

From an article about ["nepotism" problem](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2016/03/gc-nepotism-and-linked-queues.html)

> This is 'pathological' because ANY promoted node will result in the promotion of ALL following nodes until a GC resolves the issue.

So I guess it will be promoted to Old gen first, then collected.